# Validation of input mask

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-inputmask

I'm using [RobinHerbots/Inputmask](https://github.com/RobinHerbots/Inputmask) plugin to mask tel input. I wanted to know how I can validate the input to make sure the user entered the correct information. 
Thank you!

```
 <form>
      <input type="tel" id="phone" name="phone">
 </form>

 <script>
    $("#phone").inputmask({"mask": "999-999-9999"});
 </script>
```

Comment: Have you linked jQuery plugin?

Comment: @MaksimsKitajevs Yes I just want to validate the input. For example I would use this regex to validate `^(\+?27|0)[6-8][0-9]{8}$` but can't since I'm using the plugin.

Comment: So you need solution with this `inputmask()` only?
Always better to use native solutions than plugins.

Comment: @MaksimsKitajevs yeah I know it's better, the person I'm working for need it that way, so that's why.  Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation state that you can use following code to notify your user if the correct format was inputted:

```
if ($(selector).inputmask("isComplete")){
    //do something
}
```

So for your case it could be something like:

```
if ($("#phone").inputmask("isComplete")){
    /* here you can do whatever you want to notify your user that it is correct 
       for example change the input color to green or something like that 
    */
    alert('your telephone input is correct');
}
```

Or if you follow the demo they used for you it would be something like:

```
$("#phone").inputmask({"mask": "999-999-9999"}, {
    oncomplete: function () {
       //Do something
    }
});
```

Comment: @lawkunchi, I removed your addition to the answer, and certainly adding "Thanks for the help" inside an answer goes against the purpose of the Answer area. The answer should be phrased in the words of the one answering, not as you, the Asker. If you want to share what eventually made it work, post it as a new answer (if you think it will benefit future visitors), but keep this one as the accepted one.