# How to set jquery mask with range

Tags: jquery, maskedtextbox

I have a text box which I have masked like

```
  $.mask.definitions['x'] = "[0-9]";
  $(".address").mask("xxx:xxx:xxx:xxx");
```

Here I always want to add range as well i.e `xxx < 256`.
What will be the best way to do this 
TIA

[image: Unable to edit this textbox]

Comment: What do you mean by "best way"?

Comment: How to mask this text box to do only xxx:xxx:xxx:xxx and xxx < 256 always

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55116750/validation-of-input-mask help? What would happen if you used a simple validation plugin?

Answer (score 1):

demo: https://jsbin.com/pohehil

```js
var masking = function(value) {
  if (value.match(/25[0-9]{0,1}/)) {
    return "255"
  } else if (value.match(/2[0-9]{0,2}/)) {
    return "250"
  } else {
    return "200"
  }
}

var options = {
  onKeyPress: function(cep, e, field, options) {
    var mask = ["200", "200", "200", "200"];

    var values = cep.split(":");

    for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
      mask[i] = masking(values[i]);
    }

    $(e.target).mask(mask.join(":"), options);
  }, 
  translation: {
    2: { pattern: /[0-2]/ },
    5: { pattern: /[0-5]/ }
  }
};

$(".address").mask("200:200:200:200", options);
```

Comment: When I use above code, I get 200:200:200:200 in my text box which is not editable, can you please help me here

Comment: With the `translation` option, '2' can only enter `[0-2]`. So only the first input is 0, 1, or 2.

Comment: I have updated my question above and added the image of textbox which is not editable it remains 200.200.200.200 after using your code.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".address").inputmask("numeric", {
  min: 0,
  max: 256
});
```